# Call javascript function from asp Textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have seen some post regarding this question but i cannot find a solution for my problem. I have a text box and through autocompleteextender i am searching records from database. which works fine.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false">
            </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccNo" runat="server" Width="125px"  ToolTip="Account Number">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="txtAccNo" MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10"
                CompletionInterval="1000" CompletionListCssClass="autoExtender" CompletionListItemCssClass="autoExtenderList"
                ServiceMethod="getAccountNumbers" ServicePath="WebServiceGetAccounts.asmx">
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Now i want to show some loading gif(http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif) in textbox when webservice searches for data. For that i want javascript function to load this gif in textbox. and when webservice shows some data i want to remove this gif. In addition i want to load this gif if user puts atleast 2 numbers in textbox. as MinimumPrefixLength property of autocompleteextender is set to 2. if Anyone can help? i will be very thankful.

Comment: you can use [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) for element also

Comment: i like your suggestion... but can you suggest a method in BloackUI which gets trigger when webservice return searched data. so that i can unblock loading screen

Comment: i can't be that much specific but can give you a scenario how you can use in asp.net controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some properties of AutoCompleteExtender like OnClientPopulating and OnClientCompleted... use those properties to perform any task. in my case i wanted to load a gif. i created a css class and a javascript function to load gif while using properties of AutoCompleteExtender.

```
onclienthiding="OnClientCompleted" onclientpopulated="OnClientCompleted"
```

JavaScript Function:

```
function OnClientPopulating(sender, e) {
sender._element.className = "loading";
}
function OnClientCompleted(sender, e) {
sender._element.className = "";
}
```

CSS Class:

```
.loading
{
background-image: url(img/loading.gif);
background-position: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solution/logic help you out.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAccNo" runat="server" Width="125px" onchange="return inputText_Changed();"  ToolTip="Account Number"> </asp:TextBox>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function inputText_Changed() {
            var accountNo = document.getElementById('<%= txtAccNo.ClientID %>').value.trim();
            //check minimum input characters MinimumPrefixLength 
            if (accountNo.length >= 2) {
                // remove / hide your gif image
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // Add / show your gif image
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script> `
```

Let me know if any query you have

Thanks

Happy Coding